# Using UUID in laravel 5.3 model

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, uuid

I've built a new Laravel 5.3 application, and in my tables I'm using postgres `UUID` as the primary and foreign keys.

In defining the Laravel models, I created the relationships normally. However, it appears that Laravel's ORM isn't translating the request properly:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for uuid: "0"'
```

I've searched the laravel docs but haven't found anything to explain how to use UUIDs as keys. Is there some additional configuration I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is you need to tell the model that the key does not auto-increment.

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable, HasRole, SoftDeletes;

    public $incrementing = false;

    // User code
```

Once you have set this, Eloquent then knows that it is not looking for an integer and will stop returning "0" when querying the model.

You can follow a tutorial on using UUID's with laravel here: https://garrettstjohn.com/article/using-uuids-laravel-eloquent-orm/